# How to make a multi-line text box fill in different rows[EXCEL]

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multi-line text box in Excel. I have linked this text box with a cell, for example we will say this is linked with cell("A1").

EXAMPLE:
I enter "Hello" into the multi-line text box and press ENTER. This will write "HELLO" into cell("A1"). I then type, "World" into the text box and hit ENTER again. I would like this to write "World" into the cell("A2").

Can anybody explain the best way of doing this please?

Thanks, James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the link to the cell and try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)


    If KeyCode = 13 Then

        Sheet1.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = TextBox1

        TextBox1 = vbNullString

    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work greatly, but seems to give me enough to make it work. This would add "Hello" to the first cell, then "Hello world" in the second cell NOT "Hello" and "world".